# Run an android emulator in CentOS headless(No GUI) server

Tags: android

I have a virtual machine running in Azure Cloud, CentOS 7

I want to run an android app in this server, so I need an android emulator

I have tried Google Official Android Emulator, but no lucks

arm architecture, zygote always receive signal 11, and then killed, and then restart, and then killed, always loop like this, emulator never start successfully

x86 architecture, emulator won't start either

configure shell:

```
yum -y install update
yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk
yum -y install pulseaudio-libs

echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo '' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/root/AndroidSDK' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/root/AndroidSDK' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc

mkdir -p /root/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools
wget --tries=0 --retry-connrefused --waitretry=5 --read-timeout=20 https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip -O commandlinetools-linux.zip
unzip -o -d /root/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools commandlinetools-linux.zip

echo yes | sdkmanager platform-tools emulator
sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.1"
echo yes | sdkmanager --channel=3 "emulator"
sdkmanager "system-images;android-28;default;x86" 
sdkmanager "system-images;android-28;default;x86_64" 
sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;arm64-v8a"
sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"

adb start-server

echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name androidARM7 --package "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" | echo no
emulator -avd androidARM7 -no-skin -noaudio -no-window -camera-back none -camera-front none -no-boot-anim -gpu off -screen touch -verbose -debug all -show-kernel

echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name androidARM8 --package "system-images;android-25;google_apis;arm64-v8a" | echo no
emulator -avd androidARM8 -no-skin -noaudio -no-window -camera-back none -camera-front none -no-boot-anim -gpu off -screen touch -verbose -debug all -show-kernel

echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name androidX86 --package "system-images;android-28;default;x86"  | echo no
emulator -avd androidX86 -no-skin -noaudio -no-window -camera-back none -camera-front none -no-boot-anim -gpu swiftshader_indirect -screen touch -verbose -debug all -show-kernel

echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name androidX64 --package "system-images;android-28;default;x86_64"   | echo no
emulator -avd androidX64 -no-skin -noaudio -no-window -no-accel -camera-back none -camera-front none -no-boot-anim -gpu off -screen touch -verbose -debug all -show-kernel
```

Logs too long, can't post it here

arm log:
https://pastebin.com/wh230NN6

x86 log:
https://pastebin.com/V4p2GBk8

Just want to know is it possible to run Android Emulator in a headless CentOS server?

I need to try others android emulator?

What emulator can run in linux and support headless?

Comment: What's the point running an Android App headless?

Comment: Frida hook app's method and then get the data

Comment: @Henry the point of running an android app headless would be for automated testing.

Comment: @olegriabov, have you found the solution for headless android emulator running on centos?